# MVC3 HTML button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 and I dont want to use Microsoft.Web.Mvc

How do I convert this code  to be used in MVC3 ? The view engine is .aspx

```
Html.Button ("abc", "Button abc", HtmlButtonType.Button)
```

and also this script

```
$("button[name=abc]").attr("disabled",true);
```

Any feedback is appreciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am using MVC3 and I dont want to use Microsoft.Web.Mvc"
That just sounds confusing...

Anyway you can use the button element instead.

```
<button disabled='true'>Button abc</button>
```

Comment: He's just saying that he doesn't want to use the futures DLL.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Markup for your button**:

```
<input type="button" name="abc" disabled="true" value="Button abc" />
```

*ASP.NET MVC 3* does not have a built-in `HtmlHelper` extension method for a button.  You *could* always easily create on:

```
public static class YourMvcButtonExtensionMethod
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, string text,
                                     IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        // generate the markup for the input/button
    }
}
```

So you really have two options:

1. use ***raw HTML markup*** in your View
2. create your ***custom extension method*** (*see above*)